# UWP list of all installed languages

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp

Is it possible to get a list of all the installed languages with voice input capabilities (speech recognition) in Windows UWP? And how?

I have tried the following, but it gives all installed languages even without voice input capabilities.

```
    For Each lang In UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages
        cboSpeechRecoLang.Items.Add(lang)
    Next
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Possibly helpful link from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/specify-the-speech-recognizer-language#confirm-an-installed-language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.installedrecognizers(v=vs.110).aspx) will provide this information:

```
For Each culture In SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()
    cboSpeechRecoLang.Items.Add(culture.DisplayName)
Next
```

As @AFriend pointed out, you can also use `SupportedGrammarLanguages` or `SupportedTopicLanguages` of [`SpeechRecognizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer#Windows_Media_SpeechRecognition_SpeechRecognizer_SupportedGrammarLanguages) for UWP, and conveniently `DisplayName` is also available from these list items.

Comment: Hi Xiaoy312,
Thank you for your answer, but SpeechRecognitionEngine doesn't exist in UWP

Comment: @henrikl2000 have you look into [`SpeechRecognizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer#Windows_Media_SpeechRecognition_SpeechRecognizer_SupportedGrammarLanguages)?

Comment: Yes thank you.
I used <code>        For i As Integer = 0 To SpeechRecognizer.SupportedGrammarLanguages.Count - 1
            cboSpeechRecoLang.Items.Add(SpeechRecognizer.SupportedGrammarLanguages(i).DisplayName)
        Next
</code>